# Select con descripcion

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera que al seleccionar un campo en el form con una `Select` saliera la descripción de la sigla, lo cual ya conseguí, lo que pasa es que quisiera que la descripción no entrara en la `ID` del campo, es decir, si selecciono un proyecto en un campo autor rellenable se seleccione solo las siglas del proyecto pero en este caos se me rellena con la descripción también, y quisiera saber si es posible que eso no pasara, que mostrara la descripción pero que no entraran en la `ID` o el `NAME` del `TD`.

```
<td>
    <select class="form-control" name="acro_proyecto" id="acro_proyecto"  onchange="change_documento1();  change_documento2(); change_documento9(); change_documento11()" required="">
            <option value=""><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('proyecto') : ''; ?> </option> 
            <?php
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*;charset=UTF8', '*', '*');
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from proyectos order by acro_proyecto');
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<option name="' .
            ($row['acro_proyecto']) . '">' .  $row['acro_proyecto'] . '<p>' . '(' .$row['descripcion'] . ')'. '</p>'. '</option>'   ;
            }
            ?>
     </select>
</td>
```

En el anterior esta dentro del `option`por eso sale en la select por asi decirlo aquí lo tengo fuera y no me lo muestra:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo '<option name="' .
      ($row['acro_proyecto']) . '">' .  $row['acro_proyecto'] . '</option>' . '<p>' . '(' .$row['descripcion'] . ')'. '</p>'   ;
      }
```

Comment: No acabo de entender que es lo que quieres, que la descripción te la muestre en unas ocasiones si y en otras no? o que al seleccionarlo en el form no te coja todo sino solo una parte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente no terminó de entenderte, pero veamos tu código.

Realmente el atributo name no debe formar parte del Option en su lugar debe de ir en el Select, value es atributo que nos da el valor de la opción seleccionada.

Tampoco necesitas los ( ) para concatenar o utilizar echo.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo '<option value="' .$row['acro_proyecto']. '">' . 
        $row['acro_proyecto'] . '</option>' .

        '<option disabled>' . '(' .$row['descripcion'] . ')'.
         '</option>';
      }
```

Otra cosa, no es recomendable tener muchas funciones iguales pero con diferente nombre, lo digo po **change_documento1()**
Sí es la misma función pero solo cambia el número bien puedes hacer la función para que reciba el número como parámetro en lugar de escribir mil veces la misma función

Es decir

```
function change_documento( idDocumento)
{ 
    alert ( idDocumento );
}

change_documento(1);
change_documento(5);
```

De esta forma la Definimos un vez y le pasamos el IDE que queramos

Answer (score 0):

Un poco rudimentaría pero funcional,

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo '<option name="' .
      ($row['acro_proyecto']) . '">' .  $row['acro_proyecto'] . '</option>' . '<option disabled>' . '(' .$row['descripcion'] . ')'. '</option>';
      }
      ?>
```

Añado otro option al cual le indico que estara desabilitado para que no pueda ser seleccionado y tengo el acrónimo y justo debajo su descripción.